# How to turn this into function base React code?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm using Draft.js library, but I don't fully know how to turn the class based code into a function base code.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { };

  const content = window.localStorage.getItem('content');

  if (content) {
    this.state.editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(content)));
  } else {
    this.state.editorState = EditorState.createEmpty();
  }
}
```

It would be a great help if anyone can help out, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To set the initial state for your `editorState`, you can use the `useState` hook. This initial state can be a function, which will be executed only on the initial render. It's useful in your case where you want to get the initial data from local storage. In this function return the value you want to set `editorState`.

The `useState` hook returns a state value (`editorState`), and a function to update it (`setEditorState`). You can pass these to your Draft.js `Editor` component:

```js
function MyInput() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(() => {
    const content = window.localStorage.getItem('content');

    return content
      ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(content)))
      : EditorState.createEmpty();
  });

    return <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={setEditorState} />;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help

```
export function Example(props){

 const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(); // define state here

  const content = window.localStorage.getItem('content');

  if (content) {
    setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(content))));
  } else {
    setEditorState(EditorState.createEmpty());
  }
}
```

Comment: As argunement you can pass function to useState and initialize state once. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state